# Connect Ethereum Wallet to remote Parity node

Tags: wallets, parity

I have a Parity node running on a Windows 2012 server. Can I connect an Ethereum Wallet on my desktop (Windows 10) to it? It is on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but IMHO, it's not a good idea for security reasons unless you have a trusted and secure connection between machines (or never plan on unlocking your wallet). This means that you have

- end-to-end encryption between the server and the desktop (such as via an SSH tunnel) and only allow traffic over the encrypted connection and/or
- a network that you are sure other people won't be using (so you trust your router firmware and keep it up to date, don't have guests on your network, and are not worried about an attacker physically plugging a device into your network).

If one or both of these conditions are not satisfied, an attacker can execute transactions as you when your wallet is unlocked.

Comment: Currently the node only has an outbound connection to the internet. I am talking about connecting to it from a desktop on our own internal network. If I eventually allow inbound connections to Parity it would be on a separate IP connection (and card). Since the RPC IP can be specified, I assume that if it is an internal (private) IP, someone on the public IP cannot attach to it.

Comment: I would not assume that an Internet-unroutable (private) address is safe unless I absolutely trusted my firewalls and routers to be bug free. And I do not, but you might (see point 2 above).

Answer (score 0):

Just run your parity node on your remote server with `--public-node` flag.

This will expose the [Parity Wallet](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Parity-Wallet) on the servers public IP address/domain. See also [Public Node](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Public-Node), an example instance is running on https://wallet.parity.io